# Centralizer of a regular permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

I was reading the presentation "Regular and semiregular permutation groups and their centralizers and normalizers" by Tim Kohl, which is available online.
For this post I will use the same definitions: a semi-regular group is one that acts without fixed points, a regular group is a semi-regular transitive group.

Consider $B = \operatorname{Sym}_X$, $N \leq B$ a regular subgroup and $C = C_B(N)$. Then it says that $C$ is also regular (slide 11).

I can see why $C$ is semi-regular, but why should it be transitive?

Comment: The reason for this, which is in the presentation, is that the image of the left regular permutation representation of a group is centralized by the image of the right regular representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ acts on $X$ regularly then given any $x\in X$ there is a bijection $B\to X$ given by $b\mapsto bx$, which can be used to define an isomorphism $\mathrm{Sym}(X)\to\mathrm{Sym}(B)$. The image of $B$ under this map will be $\lambda(B)$, where $\lambda:B\to \mathrm{Sym}(B)$ is the left regular action. Suppose $\sigma\in C_{\mathrm{Sym}(B)}(\lambda(B))$. Then observe $\sigma(b)=\sigma(b\cdot 1)=(\sigma\circ\lambda_b)(1)=(\lambda_b\circ\sigma)(1)=b\sigma(1)$, so if we write $c=\sigma(1)$, we have $\sigma(b)=bc$, i.e. $\sigma=\rho_c$ where $\rho:B\to\mathrm{Sym}(B)$ is the right regular action. Thus we conclude

$$ C_{\mathrm{Sym}(B)}(\lambda(B))=\rho(B) $$

Of course, $\rho(B)$ is also a regular subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(B)$.

Comment: Nice proof. But the left regular action is $\lambda_b(x) = b^{-1}x$, but you have forgotten to write this inversion, it should go $\delta(b\cdot 1) = (\delta \circ\lambda_{b^{-1}}) \cdots$, just a minor point.

Comment: @StefanH I (and I believe almost all sources) define the left regular action to be $bx$, because then it's actually a left action rather than a right action. (Also upon rereading years later I see I should have used $N$ instead of $B$, but whatever.)

Comment: Ok. I see. That makes sense. But the source I used back then was probably *Peter J. Cameron, Permutation Groups* where he defined it with inversion. I guess because he do not wanted to introduce left actions formally, but treat everything in terms of right actions.